# URL rewriting with /!#/ symbol in web.config

Tags: asp.net, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to redirect my old url https://mysite1.com/#!/page1
to new url https://mysite2.com/page1,
other answers did not help, tried.

```
                <rule name="Red1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([0-9]+)/page1" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite2.com" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. The `#...` part of a URL is client-side only and is never sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `#!` per your example URL, not `!#` as in your title, add this JS to all your pages' `<head>`s:

```js
(function(l,p){l.pathname==='/'&&(p=l.hash.match(/^#!(\/.*)/))&&l.replace(l.protocol+'//'+l.host+p[1])})(location);
```

This basically just removes the first `/#!`. You may have to alter it if your URLs contain a query part before the fragment.